# What is the largest number of lines one should post for code examples or data?

Tags: discussion, posting

When folks ask questions, one of the important points (and this is something that has helped me solve problems!) is that one should provide a "minimum viable example" so that the core elements can be figured out.

Is there a maximum size/lines of a code example, or for that matter, a sample file for input? From what I gather, posts should try to remain 'contained', as links can break or shared resources might go away.  This question was prompted by a post that required some sample data ([Why is my attempt to fit a tanh(x) function to data not working well?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71008658/why-is-my-attempt-to-fit-a-tanhx-function-to-data-not-working-well/71010711#71010711)), and it made me wonder "how much is too much."

I know comments have character limit, but what about posts?  I don't see a counter while entering this text, for example.

Comment: This is going to vary too much. I'm of the opinion that ultimately everything can be minimized to a small, 10-20 lines, amount of code, but that you'll almost certainly find and fix the problem long before you get there because the bug's run out of places to hide. That's assuming that you have only one problem. More than that and all bets are off as the little <expletive deleted>ers start playing off one another.

Comment: The server has some ratio of description to code that it enforces. The more code you have, the bigger the problem and thus the more description and context it should require. If it requires very little description and a large amount of code, the problem has not been properly explored yet and the debugging perform is either insufficient or of low quality/efficiency.

Comment: That said, the REAL point (in my opinion) of the minimal Reproducible Example is to "fool" the asker into performing more and more efficient debugging. The only way to know what you can hack out of the program is to know what's not essential to the bug. The only way to determine that is to explore the boundaries of the bug. Do enough of that and you won't have to ask a question on Stack Overflow at all because the bug will be staring you right in the face.

Comment: Thanks; this is all very helpful.   The ratio of code to description is a great thing which I was unaware of, and makes perfect sense.  You don't want someone throwing 500+ lines, and having a few sentences of description.   I didn't know if that was something that should be or is posted.   And yes, I have solved my own problems with the MRE method, which makes bugs magically disappear :-).

Comment: *" I don't see a counter while entering this text, for example."* The maximum length of a post, question or answer, on Stack Overflow is 30,000 characters. This includes markdown and any other formatting. From https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176445/knowing-your-limits-what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-question-title-post-image

Comment: Seconding that it will vary a lot. For some languages like CSS you often need a not-totally-insignificant number of lines to demonstrate what's going on. For some other languages where a common convention is to condense more information into a single line (eg inline callbacks in JS, list comprehensions in Python), a MCVE for a given problem could take significantly fewer lines.

Comment: That's the truth. Some problems will require a large amount of boilerplate just to get going. For example, a TCP/IP chat client/server in C will burn through 20 lines easy on either side just setting up the sockets with the minimum safe amount of error checking. Note that if you do at least that minimum amount of error checking the odds of you having to ask the question go way, way down.

Comment: There is this problematic thing in Stack Overflow; it casts a net so wide that it is hard to always be on the same page. The example link here is a data-driven problem that you will often see in Python. That is generally a very focused question, in this case a graph producing the wrong results. That does not compare to a regular programming question where a person for example dumps their entire code base rather than the one component where a problem originates. In the Python case you do not want to skimp on the data set, in the code case you do want to trim the posted code as much as possible.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [How many hints should I typically add to my puzzle?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7283/70545)

Comment: "Perfection is achieved, not when there is nothing more to add, but when there is nothing left to take away." - Antoine de Saint-Exupery

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The trouble is, there's no direct relationship between "lines of code" and "minimal", which is not to say that there aren't some limits and rules-of-thumb. There's generally no way to reliably substitute a qualitative measurement for a quantitative one like this and expect it to work. [People try](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_lines_of_code#Disadvantages) and usually fail.

If we had a single number that meant *minimal*, or even a ballpark, very likely the community would stop beating around the bush and instead use that number directly: "Your code has exceeded the 50 line example limit. Please edit it down to 50 lines."

It's easy to see how this sort of arbitrary constraint would go horribly wrong baked into the question editor with a character/word/line counter, even if we had topic- or language-specific cutoffs. Askers would squish things down to fit the line limit, harming readability, or omit other important information essential to the problem (*minimal* entails adding code just as often, if not more often, than removing code!). That's counter-productive.

Absent a one-size-fits-all solution, it's up to each asker to use experience and intuition along with the [site help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow), other high-quality posts in the relevant tags, and just looking critically at the problem domain itself to determine how much code is appropriate to the question at hand.

Sometimes "minimal" requires 1 line in certain contexts, sometimes 100 or 200 in others. In general, though, if it exceeds that by a large amount or involves code hosted externally, it's almost certainly out of scope for SO or the application needs to be redesigned before effective debugging can proceed.

Furthermore, I can't think of any questions that were useful to me which required links to codebases on GitHub. Without sarcasm, you'll probably have to pay someone to look at it and the problem is probably not one that would interest the community much anyway.

You can think of this as minimizing the signal to noise ratio. When there's noise in posts, signal (value) decreases.

Let's say you have a 3k line codebase with a problem that ultimately was caused by an off-by-one error in a small function that could have been localized and minimized down to about 10 lines of code. If you post the 3k line codebase, you're essentially asking every future visitor and every prospective answer to minimize it for you, replacing O(1) with O(n) work. This is a huge disservice to the community -- if there is value to the bug because it's a common one, there's too much noise for there to be any good to anyone. Surely, we can find a simpler illustrative version of the same fundamental bug to become the canonical thread for that problem, then close (in theory) most everything else as a duplicate (yet again, improving O(n) to O(1)).

Usually, it's not 3k lines of code, but if you're posting 100 lines of irrelevant code for a 10-line problem, that's still obfuscation that needs to be cleared away. Oftentimes, there are other problems and antipatterns in those 100 lines and discussion and answer proposals head off the rails, focus isn't placed on the single, answerable problem and everyone is unhappy.

Most of the time, when you strip out all of the noise, what's left is a duplicate of a question that's already been asked or has an obvious answer, because the vast majority of programming problems aren't novel.

Learning to strip out the noise to expose the root of a problem is a challenging (but critical) programming skill that is the essence of debugging. Failing to minimize is pretty much tantamount to not attempting to debug the problem. The [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) offers two very good approaches to minimization:

> - **Restart from scratch**. Create a new program, adding in only what is needed to see the problem. Use simple, descriptive names for functions and variables – don't copy the names you’re using in your existing code.
> - **Divide and conquer**. If you’re not sure what the source of the problem is, start removing code a bit at a time until the problem disappears – then add the last part back.

This requires (often difficult) work that's expected to be done by the asker, not future visitors or answerers. Failing to do it puts burden on everyone else, produces questions unfit as future resources for others, and robs the asker of learning how to debug their own programs. When non-minimal posts are closed, it's a good thing for everyone and improves the signal-to-noise ratio of the whole website.

Answer (score 12):

### The largest number of lines that *should* be posted is exactly N.

Where **N** is defined as "the number of lines that are needed to showcase one specific thing, without leaving out important information and without adding extraneous information".

Therefore, the value of **N** would vary between different posts.

We can also define **L** as "lines of code in post the post".

#### Example of L > N

```
// <definition of a Duck class included>
// <definition of a Pond class included>

Duck duck = new Duck();

int theAnswer = 42;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    duck.quack();
}
```

Accompanied with a question about why does not the duck quack. The problem is in the method call, the loop is irrelevant. If the extra `Pond` class is not used at all, it is also irrelevant. The variable `theAnswer` is irrelevant.

- Include only the definitions needed.
- Remove looping constructs, control structures, and other things that have no impact on the behaviour.
- Remove any extra code that might be there but also has no impact on the behaviour.
- Try to avoid any formatting or syntax that is not needed.

  - Does not mean to avoid formatting. Just do not overdo it. And do not add something equivalent to `;;;;;;;;;` at the end lines - code that is technically irrelevant.

#### Example of L < N

```
a + b; //only line
```

Accompanied with a question about why is the result not what was expected. Without knowing the values of `a` or `b` or what is done with the result, it is impossible to answer.

- Include inputs.

  - If the code works with some collection of data, then represent it as simply as possible. For example, if the code is sorting based on field `foo`, you probably do not need the rest of the fields.
  - Also if the code works with some collection of data, then include enough of it to showcase the behaviour. In general, 3 to 10 items are usually enough as a sample.
- Include output and/or behaviour.
- Include expected output and/or behaviour.
- Include definitions of data/objects/functions/other stuff you use.

  - Or at the very least describe them in text if adding them takes up too much space and it is not actually that useful.

    - For example, "I am using X from Y library" is enough, does not necessarily mean you have to include the code for X.
    - If you have a class, or function, or a data structure where the implementation details are irrelevant, you can only describe it by its interface.

Comment: `int theAnswer = 42;` - should that be posted as a separate answer? :-)

Comment: @AdrianMole naturally. But you need to find the correct question to post it to.

Answer (score 6):

The problem with minimal is that people take words out of context. MCVE means is minimal, complete and verifiable. It has to fulfill all three conditions. So, what's the largest number of lines? Enough to create an example that is complete and verifiable.

Answer (score -3):

The largest amount of data one *should* post is exactly Zero.

Practically, it is fine to go a bit above that if one just cannot get the example to work without some minimum of data. After all, there won't be any questions if askers are required to solve *everything* by themselves and we need *something* to work with.
Usually, no one will go through the hassle to check whether the data is the *absolute* minimum needed. Like everything about a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) there is some leeway. As long as the question content is comfortable to work with, it is generally fine.

But if instead of wondering what is the *minimum* one has to wonder if we are past the *maximum* already, it is too much.

Comment: *data point* may refer to *"...a post that required some sample data"*