# Reasonable limit of code to post when asking a question

Tags: discussion, sorting

I am a new user who is very new to programming. Recently I have been working on a fitness/dieting calculator. Currently, I am stuck on trying to add multiple items to an arraylist without using lots of individual lines of code. Is it acceptable to paste your whole program to have people suggest possible fixes?

Comment: If it's working code, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be more appropriate. A post is limited to 30,000 characters.

Comment: If your code is _not_ working as expected, you can post on Stack Overflow, but you should make sure you include a [_minimal_, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), not a wall of code. Hint: you're allowed to ask multiple questions, one for each individual problem that you might have with the code.

Comment: Please note that we are not a *help forum*, but a *knowledge repository* (if you take the time to read [tour], which you haven't so far, you will see it in bold letters). All posts are contributions to it and as such, huge code dumps have little to no value for us. You will need to reduce your code to an MRE (see comment above), or risk the question get closed for lacking debugging details.

Comment: "*without using lots of individual lines of code*" just be sure to also provide the reason and detail for this requirement. Otherwise, you might get answers ranging from [codereview.se] to [codegolf.se] quality.

Comment: Also [What is the largest number of lines one should post for code examples or data?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415947/15497888)

Comment: Re *"multiple items to an arraylist without using lots of individual lines of code"*: It is very likely that this question has already been asked (and answered). It is just a matter of finding it among the existing [22,613,938 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions), though admittedly this may be easier said than done. You can narrow it down by using the programming language in the search queries (C#? [1,539,619 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23). Java? 1,848,203 questions.) [A candidate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213974/) (though an unmarked dup.).

Answer (score -2):

You can paste your whole program but it is very unlikely that anyone will go through more than 50 lines of code. It is better to give a simplified minimum reproducible example of your error; see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

It is more likely that you get a helpful answer if you post one question per error each with its own minimum example that reproduces the error. You could slice out the part of the code that gives you trouble and define new input and output for it - just like when you create tests to verify your code.

Comment: "You can paste your whole program.." This sounds like it is acceptable to post the whole program. While anyone certainly CAN post their whole program, or ask multiple questions in a post, that is definitely not something they SHOULD do. Questions that don't contain minimal reproducible example or ask multiple questions can be closed or downvoted as they don't follow the site rules.

Comment: Well, this is exactly what I have written in my answer. Stackoverflow does not impose a limit on the lines of code posted. Thus you can post as much code as you like. However, as I've written, it's neither good practice nor likely to gain a helpful answer. Please read my complete answer.

Comment: Your answer is not specific enough. It does not give clear guidance that posting more code than necessary or asking multiple questions violates the rules of the site.  Even when you tell new users what is better, they will not follow those "better" guidelines because it is easier for them. There is too much ambiguity in your answer and new users need stronger guidance.

Comment: I stand by my answer. You're free to post your own answer.

Comment: You can also edit and improve your answer. I am not saying that you have to do that, if you feel that your answer is good enough. I cannot post an answer because question is closed.